# XBAP applications won't download: The operation has timed out?

Tags: .net-3.5, xbap

Trying to download any XBAP application on a workstation that used to be able to, the presentationhost loads and then sits at "Downloading Application" with zero bytes downloaded for several minutes.  Eventually it comes up with "Application Download Error" with the error log shown below.  Also several folders are created under my profile apps\2.0 but no files are actually downloaded.

I can download the app from another workstation so the app appears to be good.  This application and IIS are all running on my local workstation so there should be no network or firewall issues.

I've tried:

- Clearing out isolated storage and app\2.0 folders
- Running mage.exe -cc
- Running the xbap permission fixer (xbappermfx_sx.exe)-- which found and fixed something but didn't fix the issue
- Creating a new user and trying to browse to the app logged in as that user
- Uninstalling all .NET and reinstalling through 3.5sp1

Any thoughts on what else to try?

Error log follows:

PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 5.1.2600.196608 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 2.0.50727.3053
    System.Deployment.dll       : 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    mscorwks.dll            : 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    dfshim.dll          : 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://clel043t2575/framework.ui/Framework.UI.xbap?Service=https://CLEL043T2575:444/
    Application url         : http://clel043t2575/framework.ui/Framework.UI_5_1_191_0/Framework.UI.exe.manifest

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : Framework.UI.application, Version=5.1.191.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=dfc8268704145129, processorArchitecture=msil
    Application Identity        : Framework.UI.exe, Version=5.1.191.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=dfc8268704145129, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Online only application.
    * Trust url parameter is set.   * Browser-hosted application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * An exception occurred while downloading the application. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading http://clel043t2575/framework.ui/Framework.UI_5_1_191_0/Framework.UI.pdb.deploy did not succeed.
        + The operation has timed out

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    No phase information is available.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [12/6/2009 6:10:11 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading http://clel043t2575/framework.ui/Framework.UI_5_1_191_0/Framework.UI.pdb.deploy did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.SynchronizeCore(Boolean blocking)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.SynchronizeAsyncWorker()
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The operation has timed out
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.

Answer (score 1):

How large is your app? The default cache-limit is 250MB:

Add/change `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Deployment\OnlineAppQuotaInKB`, which is a `DWORD` value that expresses the cache size in kilobytes. For example, in order to increase the cache size to 500MB, I set this value to 512000.

Answer (score 0):

Try configure MIME types.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752346.aspx#content_expiration